# Open the TortoiseSVN log dialog using a tsvncmd: url to search a repository

Tags: tortoisesvn

In order to open the TortoiseSVN log dialog from a web link, I can do

```
<a href="tsvncmd:command:log?path:d:\path\to\my\workingcopy?findstring:123?findtype:32">Changes for issue 123</a>
```

However, since people might have different local paths to their working copies, I'd like to open the log window using a repository url to my svn server instead, like e.g.

```
<a href="tsvncmd:command:log?url:https://mysvnserver/svn/myrepository?findstring:123?findtype:32">Changes for issue 123</a>
```

The log command doesn't support the url parameter, although it's supported in other commands.

Does anyone know of a workaround, so I can open the log dialog for a repository url?

I'm working with version 1.9.4.27285 of TortoiseSVN on Windows 10.

**Edit**

Meanwhile, I found out that I can in fact use an url:

```
<a href="tsvncmd:command:log?path:https://mysvnserver/svn/myrepository?findstring:123?findtype:32">Changes for issue 123</a>
```

Unfortunately, if I open the log dialog this way, it seems to be unable to filter by issue number. The issue number filter is displayed in the log dialog, but it seems to be unable to parse the log messages for issue numbers. If I use the working copy path, it works as expected.

Comment: You can think about `:repobrowser /path:URL rev:NN`

Comment: @Lazy Badger: Thanks for pointing me back at the documentation. I found out more, but still not the complete solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround that will work for me is:

- Have the users create a working copy of only the top directory in the repository (check out depth "Only this item").
- Have them enter their local path to this working copy in their user profile in the web site in question (it's an internal legacy issue tracking system).
- Use this profile information to generate the tsvncmd: link for the respective user when they view an issue.